# What's the meaning of 'do bits'?

Tags: meaning

In a video, two people are describing a character from a fictional show and they say: 'he loves bits, he's always doing bits' and they move on to another topic. I don't understand the meaning of 'bits' and 'do bits' in this context. I looked up 'bits' in the Urban dictionary but I am not sure if any of those definitions would fit there.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the fictional show, and what character are they describing?

Comment: Hard to tell without more context, but a "bit" can be a small skit or monolog or such.  Generally it would be something with one or two actors/commedians, running under 5 minutes.

Comment: @Saru, bit may also refer to the Computer Science term "bit," a portmanteau of binary digit.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers! Unfortunately, they don't give more information about the character. They are two people who have created a fictional show set in Brooklyn and are describing one of the characters.

Comment: In that context, it's clearly referring to a comedic skit, as @HotLicks said.

Comment: Bing Crosby --- Do-be-do-be-do bits.

Answer (score 2):

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) includes a definition of *bit* that matches the sense in which the characters in your example use the term:

> **bit** *n* ... **3 :** something small or unimportant of its kind: as ... **c** (1) : a small part usu. with spoken lines in a theatrical performance (2) : a usu. short theatrical routine {a corny comedy *bit*}

The relevant definition here is 3c(2).

Robert Chapman & Barbara Kipfer, *Dictionary of American Slang*, third edition (1995) has this take on the same meaning of bit:

> **bit** ... **3** ***n*** *fr[om] theater* A display of pretended feeling, or an outright imitation; =ACT, SHTICK. [Examples:] *So he does his hurt-puppy-dog bit/ You should see my Jimmy Cagney bit*

An example of a *bit* would be someone doing an imitation of Edward G. Robinson as Johnny Rocco from the 1948 movie [*Key Largo*](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0017010/quotes)—just a few lines of famous dialogue like

> "After living in the USA for more than thirty-five years, they called me an undesirable alien. Me. Johnny Rocco. Like I was a dirty Red or something!"

That's a bit. So is a mime pretending to be trapped in a glass box. Or a magician doing the endless scarf trick. Or a comedian riffing on his mother-in-law.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with sex. It means like what friends do when they hang out and make each other laugh doing funny pretend scenarios or what it be like if.... something. When actual comedians do it, it tends to be at a higher level of funny with much more commitment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

They are referring to sexual stuff that is not full sex. Do bits means like foreplay before sex, or oral sex.

Comment: Hi, Jumptogo—and thanks for your interest in English Language & Usage. Please consider substantiating your contention about what "do bits" means by citing a dictionary or other reference work that supports your understanding.